# Generalizing C*-algebraic results to purely algebraic situations

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, c-star-algebras

In the category of C*-algebras there are many purely algebraic properties which often make life easier, such as the fact that every C*-algebra is idempotent (by Cohen-Hewitt).  When speaking of closed ideals, this has a very nice consequence: the intersection of two ideals equals their product.

Motivated by the study of Leavitt path algebras, many C*-algebraic results have been extended to various purely algebraic situations, most of which involve algebras sharing some form of the above properties.  It would therefore be interesting to identify a large class of algebras over a given field $K$ to be considered as the natural environment where one would look for generalizations of C*-algebraic results.

To be precise, here is a specific question:

> Find a large sub-category of the category of all algebras over a field
>   $K$, including all C*-algebras in case $K=\mathbb C$, in which every
>   algebra is idempotent.  The kernels of the morphisms in this category
>   should moreover satisfy the above property according to which
>   intersections and products coincide.

Some people might think of von Neumann regular rings, but not all C*-algebras have this property.

An answer based on first principles would be much more appreciated than any ad hoc description of a category.

Comment: Over fields of characteristic p>0 a group algebra can contain nilpotent ideals and so you might need to be fairly restrictive in what morphisms you allow.

Comment: What is an idempotent algebra?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan a not necessarily unital ring R is idempotent if $R^2=R$.

Comment: Are you/we allowed to keep the involution? (Recognizing when a given Banach algebra is isomorphic to the underlying Banach algebra of a Cstar algebra is related to some notoriously tricky questions)

Comment: @Ben, you are right, nilpotent ideals should really be ruled out.  Regarding Yemon 's question I am not sure if one should keep the involution.  On the one hand, Leavitt path algebras are star algebras, and so are Steinberg algebras but, while these algebras should definitely be included in our category, their *-algebra structure has not featured proeminently in the latest developments.

Comment: @Ruy, a property of groupoid algebras is that they have local units (a groupoid algebra is a inductive limit  of a directed system of unital rings in the category of not necessarily unital rings).  Such rings have a good Morita theory due to Abrams and Marki (independently, and I might be missing a name).  Not all $C^*$-algebras I guess have this property but maybe they have an approximate version?  Any ring with local units is idempotent but its ideals need not be. Also $C^*$-algebras are Jacobson semisimple.  This is also true for groupoid algebras over $\mathbb C$/

Comment: Hi @Ben, indeed having local units is a property pointing in the right direction, and so is being $s$-unitary, but as you pointed out this leaves C*-algebras out.  In fact every separable C*-algebra with local units must be unital!  I am beginning to accept that the algebraic category I am looking for will not include all C*-algebras (hence the statement of my question is too restrictive) but will perhaps be something existing alongside C*-algebras, with similar properties.

Comment: Regarding ideals, one of the most frustrating aspect is not being able to prove that the product (or the intersection) of idempotent ideals is again idempotent.  I can only show (trivially) that IJ is idempotent if both I and J are and they commute as sets, namely IJ=JI.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I believe Juan Jacobo Simon is another name associated to Morita theory for non-unital algebras.

Comment: @Ruy, idempitent ideals need not be closed under intersectiom or product. Take the semigroup generated by two idempotents e, f with the relations ef=0. The ideals generated by e and f in the contacted semigroup ring are idempotent but their product and intersection are nilpotent.

Comment: Nice example, @Ben.  These ideals also satisfy the curious fact that $0 = <e><f> \neq <f><e> = <e> \cap <f>$.

Comment: If you have an invokution and your ideals are invokution closed things might be better.